# OR Operator in PHP Case

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I was wondering if there's a way to evaluate an OR in a case statement, such as:

```
case 0 || 3:
    echo "equal to 0 or 3!";
    break;
```

I tried || a little while back and it didn't seem to work for me, and a google didn't prove helpful.
I'm just wondering about this because there have been a few situations where an or operator in a case would have been very useful...
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with logical and comparison operators that resolve to a boolean, you can use `switch(true)` (*or really, any "true" value, due to non-strictness of checking with `switch`*) in circumstances where you want the first `true` case.

```
switch(true){
    case ($foo >= 0):
        break;
    case ($bar <= 0):
        break;
    case ($baz == 0):
        break;
    case ($foo > $bar && $bar < $baz):
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

However there are syntactic alternatives that may prove more readable, or provide more control.

As @alex points out, if you're looking to have multiple cases resolve to the same code block, you can stack them and let them fall through.

Answer (score 7):

You can let cases fall through.

```
case 0:
case 3:
   echo "equal to 0 or 3!";
   break;
```

Many style guides do not recommend this.

Comment: Many style guides are wrong, then, about *this specific case*. In general, though, taking advantage of fallthrough makes things much harder to follow.  If you have anything (without a `break`) in between the two cases, repent now.  :)